# how to hide navigation bar while transition in uipageviewcontroller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a uipageviewcontroller which I am pushing from other view controller 
following code :-

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(rideDetailsPageViewController, animated: true)
```

When I try to swipe in uipageviewcontroller navigation bar shows up. how to prevent this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide navigation bar apply below code method of `rideDetailsPageViewController`

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }
```

Comment: it works but the thing is it displays the nav bar and then disappears

Comment: Yes that is the problem.